# How to create LAN among machines on internet

Tags: ip, vpn, lan

Say i have home PC and office PC (both Windows 7) having internet connections. How to bring them together on a LAN ?

Another is if there is an existing LAN, then how to join these PCs to that LAN ?

VPN ? If yes, How to identify each machine, which IP to use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/